# Finding all information between keywords

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I want to search a given word and retrieve all the surrounding lines between a pair of keywords:

I have the following data

```
NEW:
this is stackoverflow
this is a ghi/enlightening website
NEW:
put returns between paragraphs
indent code by 4 spaces
NEW:
here is this
most productive website
this is abc/enlightening/def
```

Now I want to retrieve all information between the two NEW which have the word "enlightening". That is, for the example input above I want the following output:

```
OUTPUT:
NEW:
this is stackoverflow
this is a ghi/enlightening website
NEW:
here is this
most productive website
this is abc/enlightening/def
```

I know that grep allows me to search a word-- but it retrieves only a specified number of lines e.g. 5 (specified by the user) above and below the given word. But how do I find out all the information between any keyword in linux("NEW" in this case). E.g. I specify here the delimiting keyword as "NEW" and  call the information between any two new as paragraph. So, here my first paragraph is:

```
this is stackoverflow
this is a ghi/enlightening website
```

my second paragraph is:

```
put returns between paragraphs
indent code by 4 spaces
```

and so on.

Now I want all those paragraphs which have the keyword "enlightening" in them. i.e. I want the following output:

```
OUTPUT:
NEW:
this is stackoverflow
this is a ghi/enlightening website
NEW:
here is this
most productive website
this is abc/enlightening/def
```

Comment: Could you clarify a bit? I see three "NEW", so I'm not perfectly sure what you want.

Comment: @Ulfalizer E.g. I want to search a word "enlightening". Then I want all the information for "enlightening" starting from the first new backwards to first new forward. e..g.  "enlightening" appears in "this is stackoverflow
this is a ghi/enlightening website"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following AWK command should work (for `mawk` anyway -- POSIX doesn't seem to allow `RS` to be an arbitrary string):

```
awk -vRS='NEW:\n' -vORS= '/enlightening/ { print RS $0 }' data
```

Explanation:

- `-vFOO=BAR` is a variable assignment.
- Setting `RS` (Record Separator) to `NEW:\n` makes records be separated by `NEW:\n` instead of being lines.
- Setting `ORS` to the empty string removes redundant blank lines after records on output. (Another option is to set it to `NEW:\n`, if having `NEW:\n` appear *after* the record is okay.)
- `/enlightening/ { print RS $0 }` prints the record separator followed by the entire matching record (`$0`) for each record that contains "enlightening".

If having the separator appear after records is okay, then the command can be simplified to the following:

```
awk -vRS='NEW:\n' -vORS='NEW:\n' '/enlightening/' data
```

The default action when no action is specified is to print the record.

For strict POSIX compliance, appending lines to a temporary buffer while between two `NEW:`s and only printing that buffer if the search term was seen (could use a flag) should work, though it's more complicated.